# Unsigned byte for 10 conflicts with newline

Tags: c++

Is there a way to differentiate the first value (which is a number 10 saved as an `unsigned char`) from the newline character in the following demo code?

```
 int main() {

       unsigned char ch1(10), ch2('\n');
       std::cout << (int)ch1 << " " << (int)ch2 << std::endl;
 }
```

The output is

```
 10 10
```

I want to write to a file such characters as unsigned bytes, but also want the newline character be distinguishable from a number '10' when read at a later time.

Any suggestions?

regards,
Nikhil

Comment: Actually you're outputting all text representation anyways! Output without casting to `int` for this case (and prefer `std::endl` to output line endings)!!

Comment: I don't think casting is a problem.

For, if I change the above code to say

`if(ch1 == ch2) std::cout << "Equal!\n" << std::endl;`

where no casting is done, I do get `Equal!` printed at the output.

Comment: _'I don't think it will work.'_ Especially **what** won't work? Elaborate (edit your question please!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. You write the same byte, and preserve no other information.

You need to think of other way of encoding you values, or reserve one value for your sentinel (like 255 or 0). Of course, you need to be sure, that this value is not present in your input.

Other possibility it to use one byte-value as 'special' character to escape your control codes. Similar as '\' is used to give special meaning to 'n' in '\n'. But it makes all parsing more complicated, as your values may be now one- or two-byte long. Unless you are under tight pressure memory-wise, I would advice to store values as their string representation, this is usually more readable.

Comment: I agree... I think the best way is to shift the original 10 to its ascii equivalent! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, a char of value 10 is a newline. Take a look at an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/). You'll see that the  number 10 would be two different chars (49 and 48, respectively).

Comment: I agree. The problem is some of the files are not written by me and I would like to comply with the original database. The original data base was without any newline character and so was easier to manage. I need to insert newline characters and that creates the problem :(.

Comment: It sounds like you want to mix binary and text output? That seems odd, but you'll need another way to differentiate between when you should be reading a char as binary and when as text.